# ngRepeat not working

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I am trying to print an array to a table

Here's the relevant code

js:

```
var d = [[
 '12:00',
 'X-Files',
 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non nisi in velit tristique scelerisque. Sed quis ipsum a nisl euismod.',
 'Mikligarður',
 '2'
]];
```

(I know that those are too many square brackets but there will be more entries)

```
angular.module('angularBowerApp')
  .controller('MidCtrl',  ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
     $scope.dagskra= d;

    }
]);
```

html:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
  <tr ng-repeat="a in dagskra">
    <td ng-repeat="b in a"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But when I run the program it does not print anything

Comment: You have to explain (in detail) what the problem is... error messages

Comment: `<td ng-repeat="b in a">{{ b }}</td> is better` . You don't display anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong, you just have to use your b

```
<td ng-repeat="b in a">{{b}}</td>
```

```js
var d = [[
 '12:00',
 'X-Files',
 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non nisi in velit tristique scelerisque. Sed quis ipsum a nisl euismod.',
 'Mikligarður',
 '2'
]];

angular.module('angularBowerApp',[])
  .controller('MidCtrl',  ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
     $scope.dagskra= d;

    }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="angularBowerApp" ng-controller="MidCtrl" class="table table-responsive table-hover">
  <tr ng-repeat="a in dagskra">
    <td ng-repeat="b in a">{{b}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```